# base64 decoding php android

Tags: php, android, base64

I'm working on an app that send a photo to a server and saves from Android. The image is encoded in base64. When it is decoded it shows up all black.

Anyone know what's going on? Here is the PHP code I'm using.

```
$newFileName = uniqid();
$newFileName = $newFileName.$fileType;                  
$file = file_put_contents($path.'../../uploads/'.$user.'/'.$newFileName.'', base64_decode($file));
```

Comment: Can we have an example of what is in `$file`? (The smaller the image the better.)

Comment: Sure iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAFElEQVQIHWP8DwQMUMAEY4BoFA4AkgoEAv3eEqgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: `file_put_contents('test.png', base64_decode($file));` seems to decode your 3x3 white png file correctly.

Comment: Odd. It doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: How is this question related to Lua?

Comment: By mistake I clicked the wrong thing. Sorry.

Comment: How did you get $file? Using form POST? or Multipart POST? or with GET? Show us what $file was before this code snippet.

Comment: The file is sent from an android and iOS app via POST. It works fine on iOS and Android it doesn't. I've narrowed it down to the full file either not being sent or not being decoded right. The iOS file is about 10x larger than what I get from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're uploading data from canvas?
You need to correct the PNG data first and save it as a PNG file

```
$img_data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img_data);
$img_data = str_replace(' ', '+', $img_data);
$decoded_image = base64_decode($img_data);

$PNGfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$upload_path."/temp.png";
file_put_contents( $PNGfile ,$decoded_image);
png2jpg($PNGfile, $large_image_location, 80);
```

If you want to convert it to a JPEG, this function does the job and then delets the PNG:

```
function png2jpg($originalFile, $outputFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
    imagejpeg($image, $outputFile, $quality);
   // imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Tip: if you're uploading canvas data, put the data into a <TEXTAREA> before posting it - I used an <INPUT> and it truncated the image data until I changed to <TEXTAREA>.